# Can't get "Location" attribute from response header in karate

Tags: response, karate, response-headers

I am not able to fetch location attribute from response header in karate, while other headers are getting displayed when using below code also from postman i am able to see all the headers including location

```
 Background: 
    * url APAuthorizationURL
    * def sessionTokenPayload = call read('DIGI-3049.feature')
    * def authToken = sessionTokenPayload.session_Token
    * configure cors = true
    * print authToken

  @Authorization
  Scenario: Authorization_100200
    Given header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    * print authToken
    * def query = {client_id: '0oajtiuveymO1ES7G0h7',response_type : 'token',response_mode:     'okta_post_message', redirect_uri: 'https%3A%2F%2Fqa2-sc.adviser.ad.mlclife.com.au',    scope:'advisor',prompt:'none',state:'203475b6-836d-4dcb-8a12-7b2b2b3a2cf9', sessionToken :  'authToken', nonce:'158261204839000', scope : 'advisor' }
    And params query
    When method get
     Then status 200
    * print responseHeaders / location header is not printing
    * print 'headers:', karate.prevRequest.headers / location header is not printing
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Please paste this into a new `Scenario` and try:

```
* url 'http://httpbin.org'
* path 'redirect-to'
* param url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
* param status_code = 200
* method get
```

And the first request-response is:

```
19:04:20.612 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - request:
1 > GET http://httpbin.org/redirect-to?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpbin.org%2Fget&status_code=200
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/1.8.0_231)

19:04:21.287 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 670.62
1 < 302
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
1 < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < Content-Length: 0
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
1 < Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 13:34:21 GMT
1 < Location: http://httpbin.org/get
1 < Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
```

So you must be missing something or making the wrong request to the wrong end-point. Also make sure you read about the [`followRedirects` configuration](https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure) in the docs.